# How to get keypressed, keydown events from DataGridView data cells

Tags: .net, datagridview, keyboard-events

I need to receive the key press events during cell editing in `DataGridView` control.

From what I have found on the net the `DataGridView` is designed to pass all key events from `DataGridView` to the cell editing control and you cannot get these events easily.

I found this [piece of code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridCellEvents.aspx) that traps those events for `DataGrid` control, but that does not work for `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out.
There are two parts of this puzzle - getting keys from cell editing control and getting keys from the DataGridView itself. Here's my code. To use it, you just need to subscribe to the custom event: **keyPressHook**.

```
class KeyPressAwareDataGridView : DataGridView
{

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        this.subscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        this.unsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool procesedInternally = false;

        if (this.keyPressHook != null)
        {
            this.keyPressHook(this, e);
            procesedInternally = e.SuppressKeyPress;
        }

        if (procesedInternally)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
        }
    }


    private void subscribeEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.control_KeyDown);
        control.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(this.control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(this.control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            this.subscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void unsubscribeEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(this.control_KeyDown);
        control.ControlAdded -= new ControlEventHandler(this.control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved -= new ControlEventHandler(this.control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            this.unsubscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void control_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        this.subscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void control_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        this.unsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.keyPressHook != null)
        {
            this.keyPressHook(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event KeyEventHandler keyPressHook;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class KeyPressAwareDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
    }

    private void SubscribeEvents(Control control)
    { 
        control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(control_KeyPress);
        control.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            SubscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void UnsubscribeEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(control_KeyPress);
        control.ControlAdded -= new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved -= new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            UnsubscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void control_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void control_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Apply your logic here whether this is the key pressed event you need.
        // (e.g. "if(SelectedCells != null)")
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, for those of use that DON'T want to create our own DataGridView for such occassions; there's this method (in C++): It uses the EditingControlShowing Event of the DataGridView.

```
private: System::Boolean fIsNonNumeric;
private: static System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler^ EventKeyDown = nullptr;
private: static System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler^ EventKeyPress = nullptr;
private: System::Void dataGridView_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) 
{
  fIsNonNumeric= false;

  // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
  if ( e->KeyCode < Keys::D0 || e->KeyCode > Keys::D9 )
  {
    // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
    if ( e->KeyCode < Keys::NumPad0 || e->KeyCode > Keys::NumPad9 )
    {
      // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
      if ( e->KeyCode != Keys::Back )
      {
        // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
        // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
        fIsNonNumeric = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

private: System::Void dataGridView_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) 
{
  // Should we stop the character from being entered...?
  if ( fIsNonNumeric == true )
    e->Handled = true;
}

private: System::Void dataGridView_Machines_EditingControlShowing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs^  e) 
{
  if (nullptr == EventKeyDown)
    EventKeyDown = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler( this, &ProjectForm::dataGridView_KeyDown ));

  if (nullptr == EventKeyPress)
    EventKeyPress = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler( this, &ProjectForm::dataGridView_KeyPress ));

  e->Control->KeyDown -= EventKeyDown;
  e->Control->KeyPress -= EventKeyPress;

  e->Control->KeyDown += EventKeyDown;
  e->Control->KeyPress += EventKeyPress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not as nice as Mladen Prajdic's answer above, but maybe a little easier, depending on your situation. You may override the ProcessCmdKey method of the form or the control itself, handle keystrokes there, and check for the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the DataGridViewCell/DataGridViewTextBoxCell/otherTypes and handle key* events in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution by listening  to EditingControlShowing and adding key listener to each new editing control.

This gives me access to most of the keys, but I still do not get arrow keys.

I'll try out what Eren Aygunes suggested.