# DataGridView KeyDown Event not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a KeyDown event.

```
void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)) 
    {     
        MessageBox.Show("ok"); // to test if working
    }
}
```

The message box prompts when I press the key combinations.
But that is only when the datagridview is empty (no rows of data).
The code doesn't work when the datagridview has rows already.

Is there any wrong with the codes?

Comment: Does the debugger ever enter in the event handler?

Comment: Have you tried PreProcessMessage or OnPreviewKeyDown?

Comment: @pstrjds: unfortunately no idea how. can you help please?

Comment: @yonan they are methods on controls. Just add a handler like you have done for the KeyDown. I am not sure if they will fix the issue for you, was just wondering if you had tried them.

Answer (score 3):

The `KeyDown` event handler doesn't fire when the DataGridView is in edit mode.

Comment: I disabled the edit mode of the datagridview. can the selected rows affect the even of the datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

The datagridview has child controls with their own events. I think you need to catch the row and/or cell keydown events too.

Comment: I haven't done it myself but defining your own datagridview class something like the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325677/how-to-get-keypressed-keydown-events-from-datagridview-data-cells

Comment: After a bit more reading I came across the PreviewKeyDown event. This happens before the KeyDown event so it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to have to derive from the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) class in order to get the key processing you want. Another alternative would be to [add a message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx), but I would go with the derived data grid as my first approach.