# clear selected row in the datagridview when delete key is pressed in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to clear a selected row(consisting of datagridcomboboxcell, and textboxcell) when delete key is pressed. Following code is not working.

```
     Private Sub dgvCanaraBankCAU_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles dgvCanaraBankCAU.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvCanaraBankCAU.SelectedRows
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = ""
            dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = ""
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error? And rather than assigning each cell to `""`. But look at [this answer, it answers what you need to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200315/delete-a-row-in-datagridview-control-in-vb-net).

Comment: No error. Actually control doesnt go to that function when Delete is pressed

Comment: Ah, @user3422209, try setting your form's `KeyPreview` to `True` -- and bear in mind what I suggested before.

Comment: KeyPreview is true but still it is not working

Comment: Alright, so now that I know, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034368/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working) should help you (despite it being in C#). It's supposedly an issue many people have (just google `datagridview keydown event not firing` and many suggestions pop up)

Comment: i am using vb.net

Comment: It shouldn't affect it. At all. Whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the posted code is using the wrong index for the rows. In the `For Each` loop of the selected rows the `Row` index is `i` and its value never changes from zero. The code will always clear row zero (0). The changes below to this index appear to work as expected.

```
Private Sub dgvCanaraBankCAU_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles dgvCanaraBankCAU.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvCanaraBankCAU.SelectedRows
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(0).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(1).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(2).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(3).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(4).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(5).Value = ""
      dgvCanaraBankCAU.Rows(row.Index).Cells(6).Value = ""
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
            {

                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.CurrentRow);
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).